# Multiplicity of a zero of an L-function and covering spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-topology

This question may not be suitable for MathOverflow due to its relative vagueness, hence I ask it here. I just read in Wikipedia that there was a bijective correspondence between the path connected coverings of a topological space $B$ and the subgroups of the fundamental group of $B$. Let's consider the symmetry group $G$ of the set of non-trivial zeroes of a primitive element $F$ of the Selberg class (i.e the group of complex isometries that preserve globally this set), and let's consider a topological space $B$ whose fundamental group is isomorphic to $G$. Each subgroup of $G$ should correspond to a path connected covering of $B$ up to isomorphism. I would like to know if the multiplicity of a zero of $F$ located on the part of the complex plane defined par $s=g(s)$ where $s$ is the complex variable and $g$ a given element of $G$ is somehow related to the number of elements of the fibre of the covering of $B$ corresponding to the subgroup of $G$ generated by $g$. If one could prove that this multiplicity only depends on the isomorphism class of path connected coverings corresponding to the desired subgroup of $G$, then one could prove that all zeros of the Riemann Zeta function are simple (since its trivial zeroes are, and it has been proven that a positive proportion of the non trivial zeroes are simple).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm completely out of my depth here with the L-functions, but if $B$ is a (reasonable) path-connected space with a fundamental group $G$, then the fibre over any point of the covering corresponding to $H \subseteq G$ will be in bijection with $G/H$. Since you're choosing your space $B$ arbitrarily, it seems unlikely that it will contain any new information not contained in the group $G$ already.

Comment: Let $H(s_{0})$ be the maximal subgroup of $G$ whose all elements preserve $s_{0}$. Let's say that $s$ and $s'$ are in the same symmetry class if and only if $H(s)=H(s')$. My idea is that the maximal multiplicity $m_{\rho}^{max}$ of a zero $\rho$ only depends on its symmetry class, and that the more symmetric $\rho$ is, the bigger its multiplicity can be. I expect the multiplicity of any zero to be bounded above by an absolute constant (depending only on its symmetry class) iff its symmetry group is a strict subgroup of $G$. (to be continued)

Comment: I also expect the relation $\mu_{X}.\mu_{G/X}=C$ to hold true, where $\mu_{X}$ is the maximal multiplicity of $\rho$ such that $H(\rho)=X$ and $C$ a constant depending only on $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let's consider the symmetry group G of the set of non-trivial zeroes of a primitive element F of the Selberg class (i.e the group of complex isometries that preserve globally this set)

Do you have an example where $G$ is not trivial?

> let's consider a topological space B whose fundamental group is isomorphic to G. Each subgroup of G should correspond to a path connected covering of B up to isomorphism.

Ok so far.

> I would like to know if the multiplicity of a zero of F located on the part of the complex plane defined par s=g(s) where s is the complex variable and g a given element of G is somehow related to the number of elements of the fibre of the covering of B corresponding to the subgroup of G generated by g.

As Piotr points out in the comments, you could formulate this sentence without ever referring to $B$. Indeed, "the number of elements of the fibre of the covering of B corresponding to the subgroup of G generated by g" is just a complicated way of saying "the index of $\left<g\right>$ in $G$". Since you never mention $B$ again, it seems to me that it was completely unnecessary to introduce it in the first place.

Anyways, do you have any reason to suspect that these two things are "somehow related"?

> **If one could prove that** this multiplicity only depends on the isomorphism class of path connected coverings corresponding to the desired subgroup of G, **then one could prove that** all zeros of the Riemann Zeta function are simple (since its trivial zeroes are, and it has been proven that a positive proportion of the non trivial zeroes are simple).

So what? If one could put Paris in a bottle, then we could put the Eiffel tower in a bottle. (And this last sentence has the merit of being mathematically sound.) Solving questions like these will most likely require genuinely new mathematics and a lot of difficult analytic number theory. You're not going to stumble upon a solution by combining ideas apparently at random; to think otherwise is sheer crack-pottery.

Comment: If RH holds for $\zeta$, then $G$ is of order $2$ (it consists of the identity and the complex conjugation), else it's of order $4$, hence it's not trivial.

Comment: @SylvainJulien Complex conjugation is not holomorphic, so I would not count it as a complex isometry. Regards,

Comment: Still, it preserves distances.

Comment: @SylvainJulien Yes, and that makes it a real isometry.